# CALayer didn't response for dragging in TableView

Tags: ios, calayer

I Have Some CALayers in my TableViewCell, when I touch the layer and start to drag, I found that, I can not drag the table.

Do I have to use an UIView instead of CALayer?

Any sugguestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CALayer is not a subclass of UIResponder so they can't handle any touches. Use UIView instead.